# Can't insert values to database using JS, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a problem with adding records to the database. To be more specific the static values are correctly added to the table but by looking at the values from text fields they are EMPTY. 0 in the table. I have checked the SQL query and found that I have a bug somewhere because the values obtained from text fields are empty.

Below I am going to show all the functions related to this case, and hopefully you will spot the error which I am trying to resolve.

Function containing SQL query.

```
function updateGuestSet($no_of_keys, $no_of_fobs) {
    $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $keys = array();

    try {
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `keysets` (`noKeys`, `noFobs`, `masterSet`, `createdate`, `createby`, `keys_idkey`)VALUES("' .$no_of_keys. '","' .$no_of_fobs . '","0","' . $today . '","Jarek","2")';
        echo($query);
        die;
        $keys = QueryExecutor::execute(new SqlQuery($query));
        $transaction -> commit();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
    return $keys;
}
```

This is the function used to show/add/remove the field-set

```
function show_add_guestFields(){
    $('#guestSet').append('<div class="fields"><label for="keys">No. of keys</label><input type="number" name="keys" class="keys" id="keys" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 65px;"/><br/><br/><label for="fobs">No. of fobs</label><input type="number" name="fobs" class="fobs" id="fobs" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 68px;"/><br/><br/><button onClick="valid();">Submit</button><button class="remove" style="margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">Cancel</button></div>');

    $('#guestSet').on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;

});
}
```

Function related with PHP code

```
function updateGuestSet(){
    var no_of_keys = $('#keys').val();
    var no_of_fobs = $('#fobs').val();


    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'propertyId.php',
                data:{
                        update:'keySet',
                        no_of_keys:no_of_keys,
                        no_of_fobs:no_of_fobs
                    },
                async: true,
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(){

                }
        });
}
```

Finally, this is the PHP code;

```
if($_POST['update'] == 'keySet'){
    $no_of_keys = $_POST['keys'];
    $no_of_fobs = $_POST['fobs'];
    //echo("test");

    $insert_keySet = updateGuestSet($no_of_keys, $no_of_fobs);


}
```

This is what I get when I echo the sql query

```
INSERT INTO keysets (noKeys, noFobs, masterSet, createdate, createby, keys_idkey)VALUES("","","0","2014-11-18 17:37:37","Jarek","2")
```

THANKS for ALL help!!

Comment: what you say is the output of `echo($query)` does not match what you pasted

Comment: What is `QueryExecutor::execute`? Where does this come from? Why are you not [properly escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) your values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desired POST keys:

- `keys`
- `fobs`

Actual POST keys:

- `no_of_keys`
- `no_of_fobs`

Just make them the same.